# First Chern form of line subbundle

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $\pi:E\to X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over a complex manifold. Denote by $\tilde{E}=\pi^*E\to E$ the pullback of $E$ over itself. There exists a tautological line bundle $L\subset \tilde{E}$ whose fiber over $(z,v)$ is the line spanned by $v$ inside $E_z=\tilde{E}_{(z,v)}$. Endow $\tilde{E}$ with a Hermitian metric $h$, which induces by restriction a metric on $L$.

Denote by $c_1(\tilde{E},h)$ and $c_1(L,h)$ the first Chern forms associated to the metric $h$ on $\tilde{E}$ and $L$ (they are define by $c_1(h)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\operatorname{Tr}(F_h)$).

**My question is the following**: Can we relate the two first Chern forms $c_1(\tilde{E},h)$ and $c_1(L,h)$? For example, is there some inequality between them as (1,1)-forms on $E$ ?

Comment: What is the fiber of $L$ over $(z,0)$?

Comment: @abx my bad, $L$ is defined only on the complementary of the zero section